# Linux Install RVM without using CURL

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, curl, rvm

My current environment (including a corporate proxy) is not allowing me to install RVM with CURL or WGET for something reason.  Is there another way to install RVM from source without these utilities?  Every web search I've done returns the 'curl' way.

Any ideas?

Comment: you might try to download https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer and run it like `./<filename-you-gave-it>.sh stable --rails --autolibs=enabled # Or, --ruby=1.9.3` but inside of its script it still requires curl or it will show you an error "RVM requires 'curl'. Install 'curl' first and try again." (looking at the script) :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**modifying rvm scripts is not a good idea**

I was thinking about your question/my answer while trying to sleep... and I couldn't get an eye closed without writing you another answer. Hacking the rvm install script is really not what you should do. Rvm uses curl everywhere (installation, downloading rubies, updating, ...). And you have to download many more things -- for example gems. Replacing every curl-call in every script is not maintainable.

**proposed solution**

The good thing about rvm is, that is stores *all* its data in the `~/.rvm` directory. Considering this, you can install rvm on a remote computer (or VM), which is *as similar as possible* (same OS, same OS version, same libraries) to your development computer. Install all the rubies, gemsets and gems you need. Then move the zipped `~/.rvm` directory to your development computer and unpack it to `~/.rvm`.

Don't forget to do

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

to source rvm while loading your bash.

If you ever have to update or install gems or ruby versions, do your business on the remote computer, and copy `~/.rvm` again.

**my experience with this setup**

I use this setup (although it is automated with our CI server) for ¬2 years now for a production environment which is in a similar wicked corporate network. Changing gems/rubies is harder than it should be, but it works without an internet connection.

Edit: Added a paragraph about my experience with this setup

Answer (score 0):

You find the rvm install script [here](https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer). You can

1. download it
2. modify the parts where curl is used
3. execute the script, which now refers to the manually downloaded files

**1. Download**

Download [this file](https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer) to `/tmp/rvm-installer` .
Now download the [rvm.tar.gz](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/1.19.6.tar.gz) file to `/tmp/rvm-1.19.6.tar.gz`

**2. modify the file**

At line 148 begins function `fetch_version`. Replace it with the following function:

```
fetch_version()
{
    echo '1.19.6' # the current version, as of writing this
}
```

At line 161 (within `install_release`) the `get_and_unpack` function is called.
replace the function call with:

```
get_and_unpack \
  /tmp/rvm-${_version}.tar.gz \
  rvm-${_version}.tar.gz
```

At line 212 (within `get_and_unpack`) replace

```
__rvm_curl ${_url} -o ${rvm_archives_path}/${_file} ||
```

with:

```
mv ${_url} ${rvm_archives_path}/${_file} ||
```

**3. finally install rvm**

```
cd /tmp
cat rvm-installer | bash -s -- --version latest --autolibs=enabled
```

Disclaimer: This is still a hack. It installs rvm, but I don't know about updating (here rvm uses curl again). Good luck :)